# MySQL query for difference in data between two months

Tags: mysql, google-api-webmasters

I have a table named `sconsole` for google searchconsole api query data with the fields specified in the code, I need to find the new keywords (`r.query` field) appeared each month. I tried using this but it returns zero results. At the moment all the data is saved to the same table.
Is there any easy way to do this?

Previously I tried with a very simple query

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.*
FROM sconsole s
JOIN sconsole t ON (s.site_id = t.site_id AND month(str_to_date(s.month,'%b')) >  month(str_to_date(t.month,'%b')))
where (s.site_id = t.site_id)
```

It returned an error. the requirement is that the site_id is same and the month is the next month. This way each month should be iterated and returned with the new keywords.

Comment: Provide the table structures and some example data as ascii data table.. Also post a ascii based data table showing the excepted results.. We are not here to reverse engineer your SQL code.

Comment: Please see [mcve]